# How do I set content in TinyMCE 4, preferably within the $(document).ready(); block?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce-4

As the title says, I've looked up the [official documentation](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/api4%3amethod.tinymce.Editor.setContent) but it ain't working; here's my JavaScript (utilizing jQuery) code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    tinymce.init({
        element_format: "html",
        schema: "html4",
        menubar: false,
        plugins: 'preview textcolor link code',
        selector: 'TEXTAREA#rtf',
        toolbar: 'preview | bold italic underline strikethrough | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | blockquote subscript superscript | code'
    });
    tinymce.activeEditor.setContent($('TEXTAREA#rtf').text());
});
```

1. I've tried to inspect *tinymce* and *tinyMCE* (got this from
   Googling) instances, and they both are **objects** alright.
2. I've also tried to inspect *tinymce.activeEditor* and *tinyMCE.activeEditor*,
   but they turn out to be **null**!

---

(Cough) Somehow, after I restored everything back to where I started now it works:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    tinymce.init({
        element_format: "html",
        menubar: false,
        plugins: 'preview textcolor link code',
        schema: "html4",
        selector: 'TEXTAREA#rtf',
        toolbar: 'preview | bold italic underline strikethrough | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | blockquote subscript superscript | code'
    });
});
```

I suspect it was due to either the UA cache or the XSLT transformed result cache that made the issue; thanks again for your time!

Answer (score 7):

I have found better solution that works anywhere in code (and is not a  hack, unlike the setTimeout trick)

```
tinymce.get('tinymce-element-id').on('init',function(e) {
      e.target.setContent('my custom content');
});
```

Answer (score 6):

this is how I implemented it:

```
setTimeout(tinyMCE.init({
                            selector: "textarea.edit_notes",
                            height: editor_height,
                            theme: "modern",
                            menubar: "tools table format view insert edit",
                            force_br_newlines : false,
                            force_p_newlines : false,
                            forced_root_block : '',
                            //plugins: "fullpage",
                            valid_elements : '*[*]',
                            setup: function(ed){
                                ed.on("init",
                                      function(ed) {
                                        tinyMCE.get('testeditor').setContent($('#testeditor').val());
                                        tinyMCE.execCommand('mceRepaint');

                                      }
                                );
                            }
                            }), 50);
```

Give it a shot

Answer (score 6):

```
tinymce.activeEditor.setContent('<span>some</span> html');
```

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/api/tinymce/tinymce.editor/#setcontent

Comment: tinymce all lower case, not tinyMCE for me.

Comment: depends what version you are using

Comment: Well, OP specified v4.

Answer (score 6):

This thread set me on the right track so I thought I'd share my solution with v4

```
tinymce.init({
     ...,
     init_instance_callback:function(editor){
         editor.setContent(__YOUR_CONTENT__);  
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This code runs as soon the document is in ready state, so the only thing is tinymce is setting the content even before textarea has content.
One question where and how is the content being set in the textarea?

Secondly can you place `tinyMCE.init({ .... });` in setTimeOut.

Hope this helps.

Comment: can you try one thing before `tinyMCE.init({ ... })` try alerting the contents of the textarea.

also did you try settimeout

Comment: Thanx for the quick response; content in the <TEXTAREA/> is loaded while the page is generated:
My program pulls content from DB and constructs web page using XSLT, therefore we should be confident that the content is static before any script accessing it.
BTW, I think the order of execution is as the following:
1. Content, as well as HTML are generated at the same time (from the UA's perspective).
2. UA constructs DOM, when it's done, jQuery comes into the game.
3. tinymce.init(); initializes itself, but not yet providing an instance itself. (based on your answer, thanx again)

Answer (score 0):

I remember doing something like this once, manually adding the textarea value to TinyMCE:

```
tinyMCE.init({
   ...
   setup : function(editor) {
      editor.setContent($('TEXTAREA#rtf').text());
   }
});
```

The "editor" parameter for setup function is a TinyMCE instance, guaranteed to be there. Haven't used TinyMCE in a while, but I remember having numerous problems like this! You're not alone in finding issues here.

But why not use something like this? http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration3x:editor_selector

```
tinyMCE.init({
        ...
        mode : "specific_textareas",
        editor_selector : "TEXTAREA#rtf" // CSS Selectors
});
```

Which is the default way to use TinyMCE. It will convert your textareas into TinyMCE instances and keep the value synced between the input and TinyMCE

Comment: I've tried both approaches, neither works out for me; I don't know if this has anything to do w/ the TinyMCE version (4.0.11 to be exact), coz I don't find setup, mode, and editor_selector from official documention (under API 4.x). But I tried anywayz.
Thanx to your answer, it helps me understand this lib more!

Comment: Have you tried replicating their Installation tutorial exactly? http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Installation (This is for API4.x) You're probably doing something out of order and the error messages aren't very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I've been doing it that way :

```
tinymce.init({
     ...
     setup: function (editor) {
        editor.on('init', function () {
            editor.setContent('<p>Some content goes here.</p>');
            tinymce.triggerSave();
        })
     },
     ...
});
```